# Função para pontos que coincidem

Tags: c, funções, struct

Em um exercício, preciso criar uma função que retorne TRUE caso os pontos sejam idênticos. Para os pontos, foi implementada uma estrutura como a seguir:

```
typedef struct //Estrutura definida para os pontos.
{
    double x; //Coordenadas X e Y.
    double y;
} Ponto;
```

A função que criei foi a seguinte:

```
int pontoCoincide(Ponto P, Ponto Q)
{
    int coincide = 0;
    if(P.x == Q.x && P.y == Q.y)
        coincide = 1;
    return coincide;
}
```

Gostaria de saber se o que fiz está correto e é simplesmente isso, ou se há algo de errado. Lembrando que preciso criar a função com exatamente esses parâmetros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu raciocínio está correto e pode ser implementado de outras maneiras:

Usando operadores ternários:

```
int pontoCoincide( Ponto P, Ponto Q )
{
    return (P.x == Q.x && P.y == Q.y) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
int pontoCoincide( Ponto P, Ponto Q )
{
    return (P.x == Q.x && P.y == Q.y);
}
```